# Run shell command pipe with output redirect lively ?

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I am trying to run several lines of shell commands by Python, these shell commands are like:

```
sudo apt-get install xxx | sudo apt-get update
cd ~/somefolder
make && sudo make install
```

I want to run these lines of commands line by line, like:

```
for line in commands:
  Run(line) # line could be any valid shell commands
```

inside function Run, I would like to capture the output of the shell command **lively**, and process it. Below is a way that I have tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import shlex
def Run(line):
  process = Popen(shlex.split(line), stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if process.poll() is not None:
      break
    if output:
      # process output
      print output.decode("utf-8")
```

This solution could not handle pipe command. I also tried:

```
process = Popen(["/bin/sh", "-c", line], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

This way could not redirect the output correctly.

Anybody know how to do it ? Thanks!

Comment: Despite any redirect issues, your script cannot work this way, because the effect of `cd` executed in a remote process is immediately lost.

Comment: Why don't you pipe your python functions? Say func1(func2(func3))). And every function process the output of the previous one?

Comment: @SamirSadek to avoid long time silent waiting.

Comment: @VPfB I just typed the codes here, not tested. How can I avoid this issue ?

Comment: @blackball You must call`os.chdir` in your code instead of `Popen`. It will change the working directory of your program till next `os.chdir`. Or you can put everything on one line: `cd dir ; command ...` and use sh -c like you wrote in the bottom part of your question.

Comment: @blackball. I see. It seems complicated because you want to have the output in the screen and process lines by lines the output as it was coming from a stream. I don't think Subprocess will let you do that. You can either run a command or buffer the output for further processing. Try maybe os and put there your shell command.